# How to write to a HttpServletResponse response object?

Tags: java, struts2

I have this action class, this class takes care of my response

**Update** now passing response from `DownloadStatus` class, but it looks like it is null

```
public final class DownloadStatus extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware,ServletResponseAware
{
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DownloadStatus.class);
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private File cfile;
    private String cfileFileName;

    @Override
    public String execute() 
    {

        logger.debug("Inside DownloadStatus.execute method")

        try {
            ChainsInvoker invoker = new ChainsInvoker()
            def executionResponse = invoker.invoke(request, MYChains.download, cfile, cfileFileName)
            if(executionResponse == null || ErrorHandler.checkIfError(executionResponse))
            {
                return ERROR
            }
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/xml")

            logger.debug("filename: $cfileFileName")

            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+cfileFileName+"\"")
            response.getWriter().print(executionResponse)
            logger.debug("executionResponse :" + executionResponse)
            invoker.invoke(MYChains.clean)
        }catch (Exception exp) {

            logger.error("Exception while Creating Status ")
            logger.error(exp.printStackTrace())

        }
        return NONE
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {     this.request = request; }

    @Override
    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {      this.response = response;   }

    public File getcfile()  {       cfile   }

    public void setcfile(File cfile)    {       this.cfile = cfile  }

    public String getcfileFileName()    {       cfileFileName   }

    public void setcfileFileName(String cfileFileName){     this.cfileFileName = cfileFileName  }
}
```

and below class to write stream into response

```
class DownloadStatusResponse implements Command {   

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DownloadStatusResponse.class);
@Override
public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception 
{
    logger.debug("Inside DownloadStatusResponse.execute() method")
    OutputStream response = null;

    if(ctx.get(ContextParams.absFileName) != null && ctx.get(ContextParams.absFileName).toString().trim().length() != 0 )
    {
HttpServletResponse resp = ctx.get(ContextParams.response)
/*I am trying to get Response here*/

        response=downloadStatusFile(ctx.get(ContextParams.absFileName).toString(),resp)
    }

    logger.debug("Response: " + response)
    ctx.put(ContextParams.response,response);   /*ContextParams is a enum of keywords, having response*/
    return false;
}

private OutputStream downloadStatusFile(String filename,HttpServletResponse resp)
{
    logger.info("Inside downloadStatusFile() method")

    File fname = new File(filename)
    if(!fname.exists())
    {   
        logger.info("$filename does not exists")
        return null
    }
    else
    {

        resp.setContentType("APPLICATION/xml")
/*Exception: cannot setContentType on null object*/

        resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fname.getName()+"\"")

        FileInputStream istr = new FileInputStream(fname)
        OutputStream ostr = resp.getOutputStream()
        /*I need to use resp.getOutputStream() for ostr*/

        int curByte=-1;

        while( (curByte=istr.read()) !=-1)
            ostr.write(curByte)

        ostr.flush();           
    }               
    return ostr
}

}
```

My question is how can `ostr` be returned to the `response` in `DownloadStatus` class?

**Update (working test servlet)**

I have this below servlet which does the job of getting file content into a stream and giving it back to the HttpServletResponse, but i want to use it in above code

```
    public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fileName = req.getParameter("zipFile");

    if(fileName == null)      return;

        File fname = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println("filename"); 
        if(!fname.exists())  {System.out.println("Does not exists");            return;}

        FileInputStream istr = null;
        OutputStream ostr = null;
        //resp.setContentType("application/x-download");
        resp.setContentType("APPLICATION/ZIP"); 
        resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fname.getName()+"\"");
        System.out.println(fname.getName()); 
        try {  
          istr = new FileInputStream(fname);
          ostr = resp.getOutputStream();
          int curByte=-1;

                while( (curByte=istr.read()) !=-1)
                    ostr.write(curByte);

          ostr.flush();
        } catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally{
          try {
            if(istr!=null)  istr.close();
            if(ostr!=null)  ostr.close();
          } catch(Exception ex){

              ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          }
        }  
        try {
            resp.flushBuffer();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: why you playing around with streams and Servlet API directly while it can be done with stream result

Comment: `ostr` is `OutputStream`, but `response` is `HttpServletResponse`. Wha do you mean with *ostr returned to response*?

Comment: @Umesh: I am not familiar with downloading stuff! so what I came to work out @ first I am following it, help me out if there is a better way :) thanks

Comment: @splix: Hi, I updated my question to include my test servlet which does the job to download the file

Comment: here are few quick references (http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/stream-result.html) , (http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html)

Comment: @Ricky: Just follow the above links a better clean approach to do everything .

Comment: You're more likely to get a helpful response if you can pare your question down to the bare essentials rather than posting a big wall of code

Comment: @Don: I am just starting out on commons chains, & I am not sure which information I should neglect. So this is as it is bare minimum I could get :)

Comment: There is really a lot of unncessary code, and I it's hard to understand what to trying to reach. And also, it's better to call this serlvets/methods as *serve* file, not *download*, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using both your own commands, *and* Struts 2, which is already a command-pattern framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand all you require is how to download a file using Struts2.

You need something like this is your struts.xml file

```
<action name="downloadfile" class="DownloadAction">
           <result name="success" type="stream">
               <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
               <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
               <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="document.pdf"</param>
               <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
           </result>
       </action>
```

Code:

```
public class DownloadAction extends ActionSupport {

  private InputStream inputStream;

  public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
  }

  public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
  }

  public String execute() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filePath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads");
    File f = new File(filePath + "/nn.pdf");
    System.out.println(f.exists());
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Comment: Prime example of why linking to external sources is generally frowned upon. Link is now dead, and this answer make little sense.

Comment: @thecoshman I've added action code, hope this makes sense now. Sorry for the broken link, I've removed it.

Comment: @XCodernice work man. Not sure how I got on this question, wasn't really what I was after, but got intrigued non the less and noticed your link was dead.